# MYSQL Null issues

Tags: mysql, null

I've got a simple DB query.  Basically I want to select all rows that are NOT equal to a certain set of strings, or is empty (if it's empty I do NOT want it to be selected).

This is what I've got:

```
select * from tbl_user where secretCode != ('S00' OR 'S05' OR 'A10' OR '')
```

The datatype of `secretcode` is `CHAR(4), NULL (NO), DEFAULT NONE`

What am I doing wrong here, should I be using `NULL` instead of `''` ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your query should be like this:

```
select * from tbl_user where secretCode NOT IN ('S00', 'S05', 'A10', '') AND
secretCode IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tbl_user 
where 
    secretCode not in ('S00', 'S05', 'A10') and secretCode not is null
```

Checking for `NULL` shoud be done with `is null` or `not is null`.

Comment: Hm ok.  Now I'm trying this out (and my previous code) in PHPMyAdmin.  I get no results with more than 1 value listed in parenthesis after the `!=` ... any ideas?

Comment: Could you try again? I've updated the answer to account for `in`. Not really sure if Mysql specifically supports this, but most RMDBS'es do...

Comment: @ChristopheD Could I ask you what's the meaning of **RMDBS** and give me some links about it?

Comment: @Servant: That should have been RDBMS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `IS NOT NULL` operator according to [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/non-typed-operators.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_users`
WHERE `secretCode` != ('S00' OR 'S05' OR 'A10') AND `secretCode` IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_users` WHERE `secretCode` <> ('S00' OR 'S05' OR 'A10') AND `secretCode` IS NOT NULL
```